# is it possible to create FTP for JSP Servlet application on Linux Debian os

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, ftp, filezilla

I have a jsp servlet application. I am using tomcat5.5 as web server and the os is linux debian server.

I deploys the updated application by making its .war file and deploys this war file by using tomcat manager. So every time if I want to add any image or any other file which will be get used in application I always need to create .war file and deploy it on web server using tomcat manager.

My questions are,

1) Is it possible to create FTP of this JSP Servlet application? So that whenever if I need to add any image or other file I will connect to the webserver using FileZilla FTP client and just drag and drop the file in respective folder.

2 . When I deploy a war file using tomcat manager where exactly the jsp servlet application goes and what its exact path?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2)  It goes to `<TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps`

1) You can but SFTP would be better here

Comment: Thank you! for your answer. But is it possible to connect SFTP using a Java program?